# Django Beginner: Project Layout

Tags: html, django, web

This is my first time working with Django and while I'm finding the tutorial they provide to be very helpful, there is one major issue I'm having moving forward with my project.

The most confusing aspect of Django so far is the layout of files in a project. As of now, the layout of my project is as follows:

```
webapp/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

Bear with my naming here, I created a Django project "mysite" and an app "app". Here are the questions I find myself continually returning to:

1. I've noticed that in mysite/settings.py there is a section for apps, would I include the app I'm writing in this project in that section once I've finished it?
2. If I were to want to create a simple index.html page, where would a file like that go in this project organization?
3. I've read that static content like CSS or image files need to be contained within a simple "static" directory. Where would this go in this project organization? **[ This would be for debugging purposes only, I've read this should never be done for production ]**

My main goal right now is to just be able to view a simple html site before I begin delving into the models and views of the app I'm creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your app needs one or more setting variables, then yes, you would put those in `mysite/settings.py`
2. Create a new folder `mysite/templates/`. This is where you want to put your template files. Organize your templates per app: `mysite/templates/app/` would have the templates used by your app views. If you want to serve static templates such as a simple static `index.html`, then just throw that file in `mysite/templates/index.html` and then add the following to your `urls.py` file (no need to create a view for the index):

   ```
   (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html'}),
   ```
3. Static content would end up in something like `mysite/static` after you run the `collectstatic` command. See [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/). The `collectstatic` command searches for static files in all locations specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and deploys them into the folder specified in `STATIC_ROOT` (mysite/static).

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. One last question regarding you response to #2:

The django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template, where would I import this so that my app will find it?

Comment: In your `urls.py`, you would import it like this: `from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template`. However, in the example I gave you, you don't actually need to import it. If you use the following instead then you do need to import `direct_to_template`: `(r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'})`

Comment: hmmm i was getting a ViewDoesNotExist error with what you had written. I tried directly importing it and it said that django.views.generic.simple doesn't exist?

Comment: It might be the way you have defined your urls. Here's an example on using generic views: 

`from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^about/$', direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'about.html'
    })
)` 

Check the docs on [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views/#using-generic-views).

Comment: yea it appears it doesn't exist in django 1.5 actually. ill check out that link though and find an equivalent. thanks!

Comment: Good point. Django 1.5+ uses [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/)